# Cannot locate SDL2.dll in Rakudo

Tags: raku, rakudo, zef

Recently I've been trying to learn the Raku language, and I tried to make a simple Snake Game.
The code starts with this :

```
use SDL2::Raw;
use Cairo;
```

But when I compile using `rakudo raku.raku`, I get this error :

```
Cannot locate native library 'SDL2.dll': error 0x7e
  in method setup at C:\Program Files\Rakudo\share\perl6\core\sources\60460C9F1B4C4D337A9E1B809E754542AE8E6474 (NativeCall) line 319
  in method setup at C:\Program Files\Rakudo\share\perl6\core\sources\60460C9F1B4C4D337A9E1B809E754542AE8E6474 (NativeCall) line 366
  in sub raku-nativecall at C:\Program Files\Rakudo\share\perl6\core\sources\24CEF9BE56A579865C79D79E9E44D51012C345EA (NativeCall::Dispatcher) line 46
  in block <unit> at raku.raku line 10
```

I succesfully installed SDL2::Raw and Cairo with `zef install SDL2::Raw` and `zef install cairo` and when I type `zef list`, it lists the modules as installed :

```
===> Found via Zef::Repository::LocalCache
Cairo:ver<0.3.2>
SDL2::Raw:ver<0.3>
```

Random information :
line 10 of raku.raku is `SDL_Init(VIDEO);` and line 319 of 60460C9F1B4C4D337A9E1B809E754542AE8E6474 is             `nqp::buildnativecall(self,`

Thanks for any answer !

Answer (score 5):

I would check the documentation for [SDL2::Raw](https://raku.land/cpan:TIMOTIMO/SDL2::Raw) which gives instructions on making sure you have the SDL2 libraries installed.

As it looks like you're on windows you want https://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php

Comment: Thanks ! A few weeks ago I spent hours trying to install it with no success (before installing with zef) but I'll try to find a YT tutorial so I can finally install it (sadly I'm a beginner)

Comment: Installing with zef won't install native library dependencies; looking at SDL2::Raw, it doesn't indicate a dependency on an external lib, and has only a single test which may not error out if the native library isn't available.